Creating a VM and attach multiple Data disk from csv input using csvdecode in terraform
I am working on a solution where the requirement is to create azure windows vm and multiple datadisks using terraform. The inputs for terraform will come from csv. I am using csvdecode function in terraform. I have 2 separate csv file, one containing vm details and other containing data disks details. I am able to loop through both the csv to create VM and data disks. However, the problem is when attaching the disk to the VM. I am facing issues in accessing the virtual machine id because the keys in vm and data disk maps do not match. I need some guidance on how to achieve this.
Below are csv files and tf code.
windows_vm.csv
I have removed few fields to simplify
subscription_id,vm_name,vm_rg,size,zone,vnet_name,vnet_rg,subnet,username
xxxxx-bb11-4b1b-xxxx-xxxxxx,WEB001,terraform-test,Standard_B1ms,1,vnet-001,terraform-test,snet-001,localuseradmin
xxxxx-bb11-4b1b-xxxx-xxxxxx,WEB002,terraform-test,Standard_B1ms,1,vnet-001,terraform-test,snet-001,localuseradmin

data_disks.csv
vm_name,vm_rg,data_disk_name,disk_size_gb,storage_account_type,lun,zone
WEB001,terraform-test,dd01,128,Premium_LRS,1,1
WEB001,terraform-test,dd02,128,Premium_LRS,2,1 

locals.tf
locals {
  instances       = csvdecode(file("../csv/windows_vm.csv"))
  location        = "UAE North"
  subscription_id = local.instances[0].subscription_id
  datadisks       = csvdecode(file("../csv/data_disks.csv"))
} 

main.tf vm creation
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "this" {
  for_each                          = { for inst in local.instances : inst.vm_name => inst }
  name                              = each.value.vm_name
  resource_group_name               = each.value.vm_rg
  location                          = local.location
  size                              = each.value.size
  admin_username                    = each.value.username
-----
-----

data_disks.tf
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "this" {
  for_each = { for dd in local.datadisks : "${dd.vm_name}:${dd.data_disk_name}" => dd }

  name                 = join("-",[each.value.vm_name,each.value.data_disk_name])
  location             = local.location
  resource_group_name  = each.value.vm_rg
  storage_account_type = each.value.storage_account_type
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = each.value.disk_size_gb
  zone                 = each.value.zone
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [tags]
  }
  tags = var.tag_custom
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "datadisk_attach" {
  for_each = { for inst in local.instances : inst.vm_name => inst }
  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.this[each.key].id
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.this[each.key].id
  lun                = each.value.lun
  caching            = "ReadWrite"
  depends_on         = [ azurerm_managed_disk.this ]
}

Getting this error
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on data_disks.tf line 30, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "datadisk_attach":
│   30:   managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.this[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_managed_disk.this is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.key is "WEB002"
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

The data disk should be attached as per the VM name.
Or is there is any alternate solution to create this, then please do let me know.

You are using different keys to create the azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment resource compared to two other resources, hence it won't work.

@MarkoE yes.. I want to create the attachment by looping over virtual machine to get the id and data disk as well to get the id. But I am not able to do so.

Can you add the column names from the CSV to the question, so I could do some tests locally?

@MarkoE corrected formatting. You can see field names now.

So the CSV for the disks contains WEB001 two times or is that an error?

@MarkoE Yes WEB001 is two times. The VM names may or may not repeat based on the requirement. Like here I want to create and attach 2 data disks for WEB001, hence I have repeated WEB001 two times with different disk name and lun.

Ok, and the windows_vm.csv has both WEB001 and WEB002?

yes. It contains both.
